# MySQL History list length is always long - I'm assuming it is client connections that have died

Tags: mysql, innodb, history, amazon-aurora

AWS 5.6.mysql_aurora.1.22.4 RDS

The client complained of poor performance a couple of days ago.  I noticed that the history list length was very long (e.g. History list length 40960249).  We bounced the database as a relatively quick way to fix the customer complaints and it was assumed that this was due to some uncommitted transaction.

Since then I've heard no complaints about performance.

However, since then I've been checking the SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; and the history list length (HLL) is always bigger than what I would expect.  For example looking today:

---

### TRANSACTIONS

Trx id counter 43269350786
Purge done for trx's n:o < 43266749921 undo n:o < 5 state: running but idle
History list length 130049

I've been trying to research what is an acceptable HLL and I'm not finding much.  I suspect there is no concrete answer to this but guidance would be appreciated.

I have questions about the transaction list.

There are dozens of transactions with trx with id >= N, sees < 43268006946

e.g.:
---TRANSACTION 43269350780, ACTIVE 0 sec
MySQL thread id 1204453, OS thread handle 0xffffffffffffffff, query id 4862897092 10.219.50.220 tcc cleaned up
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 43269350781, sees < 43268006946

Transaction 43268006946  is not in the list of transactions.  What assumptions can I make about this?  I **am** assuming that transaction 43268006946  was uncommitted and aborted.  Eventually it will be cleaned up but in the mean time this is contributing to the history  list length.

Is there a way to detect Aborted Clients and do something to clean up these processes?

This application has lots of deadlocks and I have a sneaking suspicion that this may be contributing to this problem.

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_max_purge_%';`

Comment: Are huge `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statements being run?  (That is, modifying millions of rows?)

Comment: @Evelyn - were you able to resolve this issue.

Comment: If you are using a read replica, keep in mind that in Aurora, long-running queries on the read replica can affect the history length on the primary. (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/aurora-mysql-slow-select-query/#Check_the_history_list_length_.28HLL.29)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, Aurora is not MySQL, so knowledge of MySQL internals will not necessarily be applicable. Aurora has rewritten significant parts of the InnoDB storage engine, but we don't know exactly how much, because Amazon doesn't release it as open source.

In InnoDB, an increasing history list length is related to the rate of changes to data, causing new row versions to be created. But old row versions cannot be garbage collected, because there's some repeatable-read transaction that might need those old row versions to stick around, to satisfy the snapshot of the state of the database at the time the RR transaction started.

So it's almost always caused by **some client's long-running transaction**, NOT a connection that has been killed or a transaction that has rolled back or has experienced a deadlock.

It's also possible for HLL to grow if there's a super high rate of changes, faster than the garbage collection can keep up with. But it's most typical that it's caused by a long-running transaction.

How much is too much? There's no single answer to that. It depends on the types of queries you run, and whether those queries are affected by the extra accumulation of row versions. This is very application-specific.

What can you do about it? Make sure your transactions are as short as possible. Every time you commit a transaction promptly, you give the garbage collection an opportunity to clean up that much more of the backlog of row versions.

An alternative fix is to use READ-COMMITTED isolation level, so even long-running transactions don't inhibit garbage collection. If each long-running transaction is okay reading the most recent versions of rows instead of the original version at the time the transaction started, then old versions can be removed.

Again, this is all wisdom about MySQL — not Aurora. It's unknown how much this advice will apply to Aurora. That's a question for AWS Support, for whatever that's worth (good luck getting such a detailed question answered).

Comment: This app does have lots of deadlocks that the developers insist aren't a problem.  Should have put that in the original question.  Thanks for the quick response.  I can try AWS.

Comment: @EvelynDibben - Add the deadlocks to the question or start a new question.  They are worth discussing, whether or not they are the cause of the history list issue.